# Read JSON from URL

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, url

I'm facing a problem which should be really simple to solve, but I am lost as of now.

I have a url: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=bacon

Using JavaScript (not JQuery or php. Just JavaScript), I want to read this JSON string and parse it. That's it.

Thanks!

Comment: Might be this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499567/how-to-make-a-json-call-to-a-url

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll be restricted by the [SOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) (`XMLHttpRequest`s can only be made to URI's on the same domain; JSON can only be retrieved via this method). To bypass this you'll have to use  [JSONP instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839966/can-any-one-explain-me-what-is-jsonp-in-layman-terms/3840118#3840118) ([other explanation*](http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2011/10/json-vs-jsonp/)).

It seems the endpoint [supports JSONP](http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=bacon&callback=foo), so you can do:

```
function foo(response) {
    // response is already a JavaScript object
}

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=bacon&callback=foo";

document.body.appendChild(script);
```

<sup><sup>* Disclaimer: Yep, thats my blog</sup></sup>

Comment: gave you a +1 and a 5/5 on your blog for fast and precise answer;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Love your blog! :)