# How i can include json file with array in to javascript file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i have html file with javascript, app for driving tests and 2 json files: Categories of name of test and questions with answer it self. this json is dump of sqlite database. example output below.

```
[
    {
        "cat_id": "1",
        "cat_name": "Общие понятия",
        "cat_score": "2"
    },
    {
        "cat_id": "2",
        "cat_name": "Обязанности водителя",
        "cat_score": "7"
    },
    {
        "cat_id": "3",
        "cat_name": "Cостояние здоровья водителя",
        "cat_score": "1"
    }
]
```

in my engine.js everything works but my questions and categories files are not loaded. i don't know how to load then and parse to array or variable to use it in script.

for example in php i have

require and include or file_get_content but how i need to load

So i found how to load but it not working

```
function load() {

    var someData_notJSON = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(someData_notJSON); 
}
```

my html file is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./Categories.json"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./Questions.json"></script>
```

Comment: didn't get any part of your question

Comment: Please be clear about what you want to achieve and the problem you are currently facing. What you posted *is* valid JavaScript, so you can include that in your page. If you mean you want to load it from a file, you can Google AJAX.

Comment: i'm update, it's simple javascript. i'm noob in this

Comment: *"it not working"*: please be specific. What is the value of `data`, what is the problem? Do you get the wrong result? An error? ...

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at load (engine.js:7)
    at onload (index.html:12)
load @ engine.js:7
onload @ index.html:12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your case you're trying to parse JSON from undefined data.

```
function load(data) {
    var someData_notJSON = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(someData_notJSON); 
}

load(`[
    {
        "cat_id": "1",
        "cat_name": "Общие понятия",
        "cat_score": "2"
    },
    {
        "cat_id": "2",
        "cat_name": "Обязанности водителя",
        "cat_score": "7"
    },
    {
        "cat_id": "3",
        "cat_name": "Cостояние здоровья водителя",
        "cat_score": "1"
    }
]`);
```

Comment: yeah, i understand but how i can load it first? i have in html file this 

 <script type="text/javascript" src="./Categories.json"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./Questions.json"></script>

what i need to do next? how i can catch or put it in variable ?

Comment: @MixmaxMakster your answer has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499567/how-to-make-a-json-call-to-a-url/2499647#2499647)

Comment: not working, i need localy include it and put it in variable as array :( stuck on this

Comment: so i found almost this answers me. in json i need put everything to variable $data = [ 

]

and then catch it globaly in javascript