# How to put express get json into html and make it look good?

Tags: node.js, express

```
  app.get("/view", (req, res) =>{
request('https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries', (error, response, body) => {
console.error('error:', error); 
console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); 
console.log('body:', body); 
return res.send(body);
});
});
```

I have this code working and it gives me an json in my browser. I am new to programing and have no idea how i put this in html or javascript to make a nice looking website.

Comment: hint: you are better off sending off an html to start with and then work off JSON responses using client calls using AJAX (axios | jquery and so on on).

Answer (score 0):

Start simple. First determine if the body coming back from request() is an object or a string.  If it's a string, then you need to parse is using obj=JSON.parse(body) to get an object.

From there you can try the quick and dirty:

`` res.send(`<html><body>Hi! Here is my json: <span color='red'> ${JSON.toString(obj)}</span></body></html>`) ``

That should get you started. The next step would be to output various obj fields to separate HTML elements (spans, divs, tables, whatever).

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do this would be to create a webpage that receives the data from https://corona.lmao.ninja/countries and formats the data using a script.

This should help with that: [How to make a JSON call to a url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499567/how-to-make-a-json-call-to-a-url/2499647#2499647)

If you still want to do it the way you did it above, you should create a separate HTML page that loads the data from /view, then formats it. You should do this on the webpage by using the Fetch API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Answer (score 0):

```
obj=JSON.parse(body)
var jsonstr=JSON.stringify(obj)
document.body.innerHTML=jsonstr
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.