# fetch inside normal function giving error Uncaught TypeError: p1() is undefined. and if...else not giving expected output

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

```
function p1(){
    let f = fetch("https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people");
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(f.ok){
            return f;
        }
        else{
            return f.statusText;
        }
    },5000);
}

p1().then(function(data){
    return data.json();
}).then(function(data){
    console.log(data)
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log("Error",error)
})

setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Stop")
},6000);
```

if else not working in this condition but when I put return f after else block it's working fine. why I am not understanding?

Thanks

Comment: you mean its working if you use `else{return f;}` ?

Comment: this is working
       `else{
            return f.statusText;
        }
    },5000); 
return f; }`

Comment: `f` is a promise, it doesn't have an `ok` property. Your `p1()` function doesn't return anything, you're only returning in your setTimeout() callback function (which doesn't return to p1()).

Comment: @NickParsons in addition a `setTimout` is *not* how to handle promises.

Comment: @Sushant not too sure why you're using setTimeout() either - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59916857/5648954) answer which should give you a better understanding of how `p1()` might look

Comment: @NickParsons even this is not working `console.log("Start");

function p1(){
    let f = fetch("https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people");

        if(f.ok){
            return f;
        }
        else{
            return f.status
        }
 
}

p1().then(function(data){
    return data.json();
}).then(function(data){
    console.log(data)
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log("Error",error)
})

setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("Stop")
},6000);`

Comment: @Sushant `f` is still a promise, you can add `async` in front of your  p1 function: `async function p1()` and use `let f = await fetch(...)` to grab the response from the promise

Comment: @NickParsons please don't mind but why this is working `function p1(){
    let f = fetch("https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people");
    console.log(f)
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(f.ok){
            return f;
        }
        else{
            return f.status
        }
    },5000);

    return f;
}`

Comment: @Sushant in that case,  you're returning `f` which is a promise from p1, whereas before p1 didn't return anything/undefined (your setTimeout() function isn't doing anything useful as you can't access the return values from those. So you can remove that)

Comment: @NickParsons thanks now I understand function should return promise but I was trying to do same thing with if...else and  can you look this it's returning response.ok [link]https://dev.to/myogeshchavan97/do-you-know-why-we-check-for-response-ok-while-using-fetch-1mkd

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using timeouts, use async await. This works for me

```
async function p1(){
    let f = await fetch("https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people");
    if(!f.ok) throw new Error(f.status);
    return f;
    
}

p1().then(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    return data.json();
}).then(function(){
    console.log("Stop")
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log("Error",error.message)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use returning fetch

```
function p1(){
     fetch("https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/people").then(function(f){
        if(f.ok){
            return f.json();
        }
        else{
            return f.statusText;
        }
}).then(function(data){
    console.log(data)
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log("Error",error)
})
}

p1();
```