# Javascript function to send post requests, can't return object

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to create a simplified, reusable Ajax function for my project. After wrapping XMLHttpRequest into a function, I cannot return a response object. The response object can only be printed with console.log(obj). return obj returns undefined instead of returning an object. What am I doing wrong?

```
function xhr(xhrObject) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(xhrObject.type, xhrObject.destination, true);
    xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhr.responseType = xhrObject.response;

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            let obj = xhr.response;
            console.log(obj);
            //return obj; instead of returning objects, it returns undefined
        }
    };

    // Send request
    let json = JSON.stringify(xhrObject.data);
    xhr.send(json);
}
```

To use a function I pass an object to it.

```
let object = {
type: 'POST',
destination: 'request.php',
selector: '.result',
data: {a: "a", b: "b", c: "c"},
response: 'json' // text, json
};

xhr(object);
```

Thanks to solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) now I can get the response object.

Change

```
return xhr.response;
```

to

```
callback(xhr.response);
```

And now call function like this

```
xhr(object, function(result) {
    // now result will return and object, object values can be accessed like this: 
alert(result.Name);
});
```

My last question is: Is there any possible optimization for this? Or the final result is good enough and nothing else should be done?

Comment: Why not read about [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) instead ?

Comment: Yeah, I suggest using `fetch`, look into the concept of Promises/async-await (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/5648954) for an intro), it'll help you with dealing with sort of issue (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59916857/5648954) for an approach using `fetch`)

Comment: fetch was my second option to try, but I don't want to jump on other method without solving this one, so I want to figure out how to return object.