# How to pass a variable from Node.js to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I want to pass a variable from Node.js to the internal JavaScript that is inside "flashcards", I am trying to use EJS to pass the array "cardNames"

Server side:

```
app.get("/apps/flashcards", (req, res) => {
    res.render("flashcards", { cardNames: ["card1", "card2", "card3", "card4"] });
})
```

In my "flashcards" EJS file I have four span elements, all of which have the same class ("my-cards"). I want to change their textContent as shown below:

Client side (flashcards file):

```
<script>
const cardNames = <% cardNames %>
const cards= document.querySelectorAll(".my-cards");
for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    cards[i].textContent = cardNames[i] + ", Score: 0";
}
</script>
```

I get an error:

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'"

How can I send a file from Node.js to the internal or even external JavaScript? The logic MUST be separate from the html elements so it doesn't get confusing.
It doesn't have to be EJS, I'm willing to use other methods as long as I can achieve results.

**UPDATE: I found two solutions:**

**First Solution (Using EJS)**:

```
let cardNames = '<%= cardNames %>'
cardNames = cardNames.split(",")
```

**Second Solution (as Nick Parsons suggested in the comments)**:
Using fetch requests.

Comment: Small typo: `<% cardNames %>` should be `<%= cardNames %>`. See [Tags section in documentation](https://ejs.co/#docs)

Comment: Consider making a fetch request to get this data if you want to avoid some of these pitfalls: [Is it good practice to echo PHP code into inline JS?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/421991)

Comment: @Reyno This is the error that I got: "Missing initializer in const declaration",

Comment: @NickParsons Thank you, something like this? 
async function getInfo(path) {
    const res = await fetch(baseUrl + path,
        {
            method: "GET"
        })
    const data = await res.json();
    return data;
}

Comment: @Mario Yeah something like that (you can also confirm that the http response status is OK [[example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59916857/5648954)])

Comment: Do not use `let cardNames = '<%= cardNames %>'.split(",")` - that will break as soon as a card name contains an apostrophe (or linebreak, or backslash, …)! Better use `const cardNames = <%= JSON.stringify(cardNames) %>;`, though that might still break if a card name contains html (in particular `</script>`) - I'm not quite sure how ejs handles escaping there

Comment: @Bergi That's a good point, thank you. I ended up using fetch requests, they make more sense in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

you first get the variables and then simply pass then like this

and also you got the error coz you are accessing it in wrong way, as when this variable is reaching in ejs it will be in string so first convert that variable to array first like this
const cardNames = <% cardNames %>.trim().split(",")

```js
app.get("/apps/flashcards", (req, res) => {
    const cardNames = ["card1", "card2", "card3", "card4"];
    res.render("flashcards", { cardNames });
});
```

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: on ejs side try this 
const cardNames = <% cardNames %>.trim().split(",")

Answer (score -1):

To pass a variable from Node.js to JavaScript, you can do so by embedding the JavaScript code within your Node.js script or by using a Node.js library like vm (Virtual Machine) or node-ipc (Inter-Process Communication).

Answer (score -2):

try

```
<script>
var cardNames = <%= cardNames %>
var cards= document.querySelectorAll(".my-cards");
for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    cards[i].textContent = cardNames[i] + ", Score: 0";
}
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.